# How to find missing days from an array of NSDates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I have an NSMutableArray of ordered NSDates. I am looking for a method  that returns all of the days (in NSDate form) that are missing from the original array between the earliest date in the array and now. I only care about the year, month, and day portion of the NSDate when checking for equality. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *missingDates;
for (NSDate *date in allDatesBetweenOldestDateAndNow){
    if (date isNotIn: myDates)
        [missingDates addObject:date];
return missingDates;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if it's an ordered array you only need to determine whether two adjacent dates in the array are adjacent days or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `NSDateComponents` and Apple has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW1) for using them.

[This guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) by Apple explains how to perform calculations date `NSDateComponents` to perform tasks similar to yours.

Comment: Just to add a little bit more, an NSDate is a singular moment and time . Its year month and day will be entirely dependent on the locale, which is why you will need to use NSDateComponents to do what you want to do.

Comment: @HotLicks - It is the wrong tool for the job. NSDateFormatter is meant to create a string representation of the date, not for doing date calculations. Yeah, you can get it to work, but you are asking for trouble with edge cases, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks - If they were known, I would tell you :) Regardless, why would you rather use the date formatter rather than NSDateComponents?

Comment: Last time I used `NSDateFormatter` the performance was vastly inferior to using `NSDateComponents`. Since the question was related to going through list of dates and the list had the potential to be big, answered with the option I figured would have the best performance, not the least code. Performance may have improved since then though, I encountered this when using iOS 5.0

Comment: @DBD - If you created a new formatter for each iteration, I'd believe that.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to subclass `NSDate` and add a method that compares dates without considering the time:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object
{
    NSDateComponents* c1= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: self ];
    NSDateComponents* c2= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: object ];
    return [c1 isEqual: c2];
}
```

The rest comes natural: to see if your array has a date you can use this method.

Comment: That won't tell you if they're one day apart.

Comment: This was for the  "if (date isNotIn: myDates)" part: if he has an array of custom NSDate objects with isEqual: overridden, he could know whether an object is or is not in the array, using containsObject: .

Comment: So how do you tell what dates are missing?

Comment: The algorithm I though is: create an array of dates between the two dates, and eliminate every date that is in his dates array. You're right if you think it's not efficient, you're one will do it better. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Not compiled -- there are probably some tupos.

```
NSDateFormatter* dayFmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFmt setTimeZone:<whatever time zone you want>];
[dayFmt setDateFormat:@"g"];
NSInteger lastDay = [[dayFmt stringFromDate:startDate] integerValue];
// Note:  We assume that myDates is sorted, as stated.
for (NSDate* myDate in myDates) {
    NSInteger myDay = [[dayFmt stringFromDate:myDate] integerValue];
    while (myDay > lastDay+1) {
        lastDay++;
        NSDate* newDate = [dayFmt dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", lastDay]];
        [missingDates addObject:newDate];
    }
}
```

(I'll leave it as an exercise for the user to figure out how to fill in any missing dates between the last array entry and some arbitrary end date.)

(It should also be noted that the code assumes there are no duplicate dates in the array.  Easily handled, but another exercise for the user.)